# Saving only the last duplicate by group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, distinct

I have an example dataset:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date = c("6/1/22", "6/2/22", "6/3/22",
           "6/1/22", "6/2/22", "6/2/22", "6/3/22",
           "6/2/22", "6/2/22", "6/2/22", "6/3/22", "6/4/22"),
  sub = c(1101, 1101, 1101,
          1102, 1102, 1102, 1102,
          1103, 1103, 1103, 1103, 1103),
  text = c("a", "b", "c",
           "d","e", "f", "g",
           "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"))
```

There are some `sub`s that have repeated entries for some dates (e.g. 1102, 1103). I want to keep ONLY **the bottom most row** for each sub if there are duplicated entries in the `date` column. These are the two example outputs I want from this dataframe.

**Output 1:** A dataframe where there are unique dates for each sub

```
output1 <- data.frame(
  date = c("6/1/22", "6/2/22", "6/3/22",
           "6/1/22", "6/2/22", "6/3/22",
           "6/2/22", "6/3/22", "6/4/22"),
  sub = c(1101, 1101, 1101,
          1102, 1102, 1102,
          1103, 1103, 1103),
  text = c("a", "b", "c",
           "d","f", "g",
           "j", "k", "l")
)
```

**Output 2:** A dataframe with ALL entries of the `sub`s and `date`s where there are multiple copies.

```
output2 <- data.frame(
  date = c("6/2/22", "6/2/22",
           "6/2/22", "6/2/22", "6/2/22"),
  sub = c(1102, 1102,
          1103, 1103, 1103),
  text = c("e", "f",
           "h", "i", "j")
)
```

I have seen solutions for this using `distinct()`, but that usually only keeps the first row with the duplicated value. I would like the latest value (e.g. the bottom most row of the duplicated entry). Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Task 1

With `dplyr`, you can use `slice_tail()` by `sub` and `date`:

```r
example %>%
  slice_tail(by = c(sub, date))

#     date  sub text
# 1 6/1/22 1101    a
# 2 6/2/22 1101    b
# 3 6/3/22 1101    c
# 4 6/1/22 1102    d
# 5 6/2/22 1102    f
# 6 6/3/22 1102    g
# 7 6/2/22 1103    j
# 8 6/3/22 1103    k
# 9 6/4/22 1103    l
```

---

###### Task 2

Use `filter(n() > 1)` by `sub` and `date`:

```r
example %>%
  filter(n() > 1, .by = c(sub, date))

#     date  sub text
# 1 6/2/22 1102    e
# 2 6/2/22 1102    f
# 3 6/2/22 1103    h
# 4 6/2/22 1103    i
# 5 6/2/22 1103    j
```

Answer (score 1):

They key is to use `fromLast = TRUE` in the base [`duplicated()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/duplicated) function.

### dplyr approach

As you've tagged [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), here is an approach using that package. First, create a column indicating whether each date is duplicated, starting from the last date by group:

```r
library(dplyr)
example  <- example |>
        group_by(sub) |>
        mutate(duplicate_date = duplicated(date, fromLast = TRUE))
```

Then for the first output simply filter those case where there is a duplicated date, by `sub`:

```r
output_1  <- example |>
        filter(!duplicate_date ) |>
        select(-duplicate_date)

output_1
#   date     sub text
#   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
# 1 6/1/22  1101 a
# 2 6/2/22  1101 b
# 3 6/3/22  1101 c
# 4 6/1/22  1102 d
# 5 6/2/22  1102 f
# 6 6/3/22  1102 g
# 7 6/2/22  1103 j
# 8 6/3/22  1103 k
# 9 6/4/22  1103 l
```

For the second, group by `date` and `sub` and filter the cases where there are any duplicate dates, by group:

```r
output_2  <- example |>
        group_by(sub, date) |>
        filter(any(duplicate_date)) |>
        select(-duplicate_date)

output2
#     date  sub text
# 1 6/2/22 1102    e
# 2 6/2/22 1102    f
# 3 6/2/22 1103    h
# 4 6/2/22 1103    i
# 5 6/2/22 1103    j
```

Just to confirm these are the same as the `output1` and `output2` you posted (you need to convert to `data.frame` first or they will not be identical as `dplyr` produces a `tbl_df`:

```r
identical(data.frame(output_1), output1) # TRUE
identical(data.frame(output_2), output2) # TRUE
```

### base R approach

If you want to use base R, here is a method that does essentially the same thing, using [`tapply()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/tapply). Output 1:

```r
example  <- within(example, duplicate_date  <- unlist(
    tapply(date, sub, \(x) duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))
))
output_1  <- with(example, example[!duplicate_date,])
```

Output 2:

```r
duplicate_sub_date <- with(example, 
    tapply(duplicate_date, list(date, sub), any)
)
output_2  <- example[diag(duplicate_sub_date[example$date, as.character(example$sub)]), ]
```

This is basically the same logic as the `dplyr` approach and produces the same output, though you get a `data.frame` rather than a `tbl_df`.